# How to get ldap tree structure using php?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I have an active directory record of users with `ou's` and `subou's`. I want to get the whole tree structure of the AD.

for example,

```
- Group A
    - Sub Group a1
    - Sub Group a2
 - Group B
    - Sub Group b1
    - Sub Group b2
 - Group C
    - Sub Group c1
    - Sub Group c2
```

I have got a list of all `ou's` and `subou's`. but I want it as a structure like above example.

My code:

```
$ldap_base_dn = 'DC=example,DC=com'; 
$filter="(objectClass=organizationalunit)";
$arr= array("dn", "ou");
$sr=ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $filter, $arr);
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $sr);
for ($i=0; $i < $info["count"]; $i++) {
  echo $info[$i]["dn"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: ou's and subou's ? It's confusing